# ArrayList not returning expected result

Tags: powershell

Why does this code not work?

```
$method = {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$array;
    for ($i=0; $i -le 50; $i++) { $array += $i }
}
```

Executing the scriptblock with:

```
&$method
```

Shows on the console:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

when it should print 50 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `ArrayList` type emits the index at which a new item was inserted. Cast the expression to `[void]`, pipe it to `Out-Null` or assign it to `$null` to supress this output:

```
[void]$array.Add($i)
# or
$array.Add($i) |Out-Null
# or
$null = $array.Add($i)
```

Avoid piping to `Out-Null` if you do this many times, casting or assigning is much faster than piping.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted shouldn't generate any output at all, unless you already have a variable `$array` defined in the parent scope. The statement

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$array
```

casts the value of the variable `$array` to the type `ArrayList` and echoes it. If the variable has a value in the parent scope the statement will output the value as an array list, otherwise the output will be null. The subsequent loop will not use that variable, but instead increment a new (local) variable `$array`. You can verify that by placing a statement `$array.GetType().FullName` at the end of the scriptblock. You'll get `System.Int32`, not `System.Collections.ArrayList` (or `System.Object[]`) as you might expect.

If you want to instantiate an `ArrayList` object, add numbers to it, and output that list at the end of the scriptblock, you need to change your code to something like this:

```
$method = {
    [Collections.ArrayList]$array = @()
    for ($i=0; $i -le 50; $i++) { $array += $i }
    $array
}
```

Note the assignment operation in the first statement.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $sb = { [Collections.ArrayList]$a; 0..50 | % { $a += $_ }; $a.GetType().FullName; $a }
PS C:\> &$sb
System.Int32
1275
PS C:\> $sb = { [Collections.ArrayList]$a = @(); 0..50 | % { $a += $_ }; $a.GetType().FullName; $a }
PS C:\> &$sb
System.Collections.ArrayList
0
1
...
49
50
```